# In Microsoft's Internet Explorer, what does the "Install new versions automatically" checkbox really do?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, windows-update, internet-explorer-11

In Windows 7 SP1, Microsoft's Internet Explorer 11 has a checkbox in the `About` dialog box labelled *"Install new versions automatically"*.

What does this really do?  If it is enabled, does it result in frequent automatic queries to Microsoft servers to see if there is a new version?

Does it really mean "Check for new versions, download them, and install them automatically"?

If Windows Update is used manually (not in automatic mode), what are the positives / negatives of having this checked or unchecked?

Is it really just a backup setting in case someone disables Windows Update, so at least IE will get updated?

Answer (score 1):

If you tick this option, Windows Update will also look for updates to Internet Explorer (minor revisions are released periodically). If you don't tick this option, you won't see any updates to Internet Explorer come down with your Windows updates.

Windows updates still need to run to get the updates for Internet Explorer.

I believe you also need the tick box stating `Get updates for other Microsoft products` in Windows update checked.